# Jquery The name '' is does not exists in the current context

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Although there are several same questions, I'm very curious regarding this specific case.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  if ($('#msg').val() != '' && $('#msgSuccess').val() == 'true') {
    var msg = $('#msg').val();
    var t = $('#msg').val().toString();
    toastr.success("@_localizer[t]");
  }
});
```

variable `t` has some message which represents the key for my localization file.
I have issue to pass that variable (string) to my mvc _localizer.
Where I go wrong with this?

If I add simple `console.log(t)` it works. So Im guessing that is the localizer is a problem.

I'm using `@inject IViewLocalizer _localizer` from AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

Comment: Start here: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429)

Comment: So, Icant pass the variable? I know that i can pass pure string for example `toastr.success("@_localizer["SuccessMessage"]");`

Comment: If `@_localizer` is backend code? You can't, as the back-end will have already finished running

Comment: @Stefan0309 yes, you can pass a string, *if you have the string on the server*. However, `t` completely client-side, so you cannot expect to get the value of `t` *after* when that code runs on a completely different machine.

Comment: @Stefan0309 if you want to dynamic js should start new request ajax, websocket etc.  
or you can place all variables to javascript at start